# Please recommend me a professional keepalive solution for our monitoring server

Tags: asp.net, monitoring, system-administration

I'm looking for a tool that can be installed on our monitoring server and which allows us to perform scheduled requests to our web sites in order to keep them from shutting down (asp.net).

I don't want to use a web service since we already have a dedicated monitoring server. Our monitoring software doesn't really have the ability to do this without using some ugly workaround.

I could probably write my own but I'm a bit short on time atm.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about using [wget for Windows](http://users.ugent.be/~bpuype/wget/) and a scheduled task?